# BOBJ. Change object underlying field based on what is selected in the query

Tags: sql, business-objects

In BOBJ is there a way to change the formula of the object based on what's being selected in the query?

For example, TradeValue usually equals to dbo.Trade.TradeValue, but if SalesPerson is selected in the query along with TradeValue, I would like TradeValue to be dbo.Trade.TradeValue * Salesperson.Percentage.

Any workarounds suggested will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way for a particular object to detect the presence of another object in the query, so you would need two objects for `TradeValue` and `TradeValue * SalesPerson.Percentage`.

The only workaround I can think of is to create a prompt that asks the user whether `SalesPerson.Percentage` should be included in the calculation.  Something like:

```
TradeValue * case when @variable("Multiply by SalesPerson Percentage") = 'Y'
                  then SalesPerson.Percentage
                  else 1 end
```

Comment: Thank you, Joe. I have plenty of objects where I want to change the underlying formula based on the selected query, so I guess the prompt is not really an option.

Comment: The prompt would be displayed once per refresh, even if you have multiple objects that reference it.